# Android Intent Listview in Another page with a Searchview

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-xml, searchview

Please Help! I really need this app. today.

This is the main page of the app.

[Mainpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gdex.jpg)
Then after that, when you search and you click one of that word I want to display like this,

[Secondpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VKQp.jpg)
but how ?

This is my codes :

**MainActivity.class**

```
package com.skholingua.android.searchview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater.Filter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private SearchView searchView;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    private final String[] stateList = { "Example", "Goa", "Karnataka",
            "Kerala", "Maharashtra", "Madhya Pradesh", "Tamil Nadu" };
    private final String[] anotherStringArray = { "Example_description", "Goa_description", "Karnataka_description",
                    "Kerala_description", "Maharashtra_description", "Madhya Pradesh_description", "Tamil Nadu_description" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stateList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        // Sets the default or resting state of the search field.
        // If true, a single search icon is shown by default and
        // expands to show the text field and other buttons when pressed
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        // Sets the hint text to display in the query text field
        searchView.setQueryHint("State Name");

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String stateName = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
                //String stateName = stateList[position];
                //Log.e("Selected State Name", stateName);

                // Put selected state to intent.
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("selectedState", stateName);
                intent.putExtra("anotherStringArray",anotherStringArray[position]);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    // Called when the query text is changed by the user.

     @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            android.widget.Filter filter = adapter.getFilter();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                filter.filter("");
            } else {
                filter.filter(newText);
            }
            return true;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      tools:context="com.skholingua.android.searchview.MainActivity" >

<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

</SearchView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

</ListView>

     </RelativeLayout>
```

**NextActivity.class**

```
package com.skholingua.android.searchview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NextActivity extends Activity {

    TextView t1,t2;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.next);  

        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name1);
        t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name2);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String state_name= getIntent().getExtras().getString("selectedState");
        String stateDescription= getIntent().getExtras().getString("anotherStringArray");

        t1.setText(state_name); 
        t2.setText(stateDescription);

    }

}
```

**next.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000"
         />



</RelativeLayout>
```

I really need this app. Hope there's someone who will help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Which part do you need help with? Do you know how to go from one activity to another? Do you know how to respond to clicks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add description for each  **stateList** in **anotherStringArray** with respective index. And you can simply get description from list item position.

```
private final String[] stateList = { "Example", "Goa", "Karnataka",
            "Kerala", "Maharashtra", "Madhya Pradesh", "Tamil Nadu" };
private final String[] anotherStringArray = { "Example_description", "Goa_description", "Karnataka_description",
                    "Kerala_description", "Maharashtra_description", "Madhya Pradesh_description", "Tamil Nadu_description" };


         listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        String stateName = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
                        Log.e("Selected State Name", stateName);

                        // Put selected state to intent.
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("selectedState", stateName);
                        intent.putExtra("anotherStringArray",anotherStringArray[position])
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

And on NextActivity

```
String state_name= getIntent().getExtras().getString("selectedState");
String stateDescription= getIntent().getExtras().getString("anotherStringArray");
```

Comment: But why is it that only the description will display the name is not displaying.

Comment: what are you getting in Log.e("Selected State Name", stateName); this log

Comment: Try this   String stateName = stateList[position];

Comment: Still the same, only the description will display . I want the name and the description will display .

Comment: What are you getting in logcat?

Comment: No , I just want to display the name and the description in the NextActivity.class but sad to say only the description will display .

Comment: Can you paste NextActivity and its layout and your adapter too here so that we can look at.

Comment: your one textview is overlapping another in nextactivity layout. Replace RelativeLayout to LinearLayout with android:orientation="vertical"

Comment: I have one last question. How can I separate the arrays in MainActivity.class to another file ? Can you show me how ? Thank you so much for your help .

Comment: What do you mean by file??

Comment: What I mean is those two String (String[] stateList and String[] anotherStringArray ) I just separate that into another class or just in String.xml . But how can I separate those ?

Comment: I am not getting the meaning of separate.  Sorry please explain it

Comment: I mean that , those inside the String[] stateList = { "Example", "Goa", "Karnataka","Kerala", "Maharashtra", "Madhya Pradesh", "Tamil Nadu" };. I just want to move this to String.xml . That's what i mean.

Comment: I have a problem about that . when I search a one of the word the description is still the same . like this [Picture](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2SE2JZYuezjWEpCS09jZ3dmUnc)  [Picture2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2SE2JZYuezjcGZzOFNrdHBoZVk)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String stateName = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
            Log.e("Selected State Name", stateName);

            // Put selected state to intent.
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("selectedState", stateName);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

On next activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = intent.getStringExtra("selectedState");
textView.setText(name); //textView on next activity
```

NextActivity:

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.next);  

       textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
       Intent intent = getIntent();
       String name = intent.getStringExtra("selectedState");
       textView.setText(name); 
   }
}
```

Comment: How can I display this  [This pic ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gdex.jpg) to NextActivity.class ?

Comment: On next activity you can get value from Intent to string and display it. Check my edited answer.

Comment: I mean this output [Check this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VKQp.jpg) . to NextActivity.class

Comment: you should have textview on next activity, on that textView set the value which you get from intent. check edited answer

Comment: I updated my codes . but it says unfortunately close .

Comment: @JAHaha use glide to display image from url.

Comment: @RajeshSuthar  It is okay now, but what if I will make another array string in MainActivity.class  and when I press each one of the listview will display in the NextActivity.class like this  [Example Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nknsm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'`

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Glide.with(this)
    .load("IMAGE URL HERE")
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.imagenotfound)
    .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. There is problem in your NextActivity. **And Most important is where are you getting id of text view**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String stateName = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
            Log.e("Selected State Name", stateName);

            // Put selected state to intent.
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("selectedState", stateName);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

In Your Next Activity

```
String name= getIntent().getExtras().getString("selectedState");
```

Comment: It is okay now, how can I add another string array in the MainActivity.class and when I press each one of the listview it will display in the NextActivity.class like this [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nknsm.jpg). Hope you will help me. I really need this. Thank you .

Comment: I have a problem about that . when I search a one of the word the description is still the same . like this [Picture](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2SE2JZYuezjcGZzOFNrdHBoZVk)  [Picture2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2SE2JZYuezjQmNFSm45RHloT3c)